# How to get a range of months over a span of two years in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get a previous range of months based on the range users choose. For example if user choose: **July-2015 to September-2015**. I can get numeric month values using below object.

```
var months = {January: 1, February: 2, March: 3, April: 4, May: 5, June: 6, July: 7, August: 8, September: 9, October: 10, November: 11, December: 12};
```

Then I can use this logic to figure out the previous range - http://jsfiddle.net/0cq5nprt/

```
var currStartMonth = 7,
  currEndMonth = 9,
  monthRange = (currEndMonth - currStartMonth) + 1,
  prevStartMonth = currStartMonth - monthRange,
  prevEndMonth = (prevStartMonth + monthRange) - 1;
```

The problem I run into is when the range is over span of two years so it's like: **December-2014 to January-2015**. Here it should be October-2014 to November-2014.

Hope my question is clear. Any advice will be very helpful!

Comment: what are expected results?

Comment: It would be Oct-2014 to Nov-2014. I'm only looking for the range of months, year is not really important but it screws up my logic :(

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you should use year in your calculations. something like below.

```
var yearDiff = endYear - currentYear
if yearDiff = 0 {
   monthRange = (currEndMonth - currStartMonth) + 1,
   prevStartMonth = currStartMonth - monthRange,
   prevEndMonth = (prevStartMonth + monthRange) - 1;
} else {
   calcEndMonth = calcEndMonth + 12
   monthRange = (calcEndMonth - currStartMonth) + 1,
   prevStartMonth = curgstartmonth - monthRange,
   prevEndMonth = (prevStartMonth + monthRange) - 1;
   if prevEndMonth > 12 {
      prevEndYear = curEndYear - 1
      prevEndMonth = prevEndMonth - 12
   }
}
```

Considering your example December-2014 to January-2015

```
var yearDiff = endYear - currentYear
// yearDiff = 2015 - 2014 = 1

{
   calcEndMonth = calcEndMonth + 12
   //calcEndMonth = 1 + 12 = 13

   monthRange = (calcEndMonth - currStartMonth) + 1,
   //monthRange = (13 - 12) + 1 = 2

   prevStartMonth = curStartmonth - monthRange,
   //prevStartMonth = 12 (December) - 2 = 10(October)

   prevEndMonth = (prevStartMonth + monthRange) - 1;
   //prevEndMonth = (10 + 2) - 1 = 11(November)

   if prevEndMonth > 12 {
      prevEndYear = curEndYear - 1
      prevEndMonth = prevEndMonth - 12

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Can you explain your code? What would be 'calcEndMonth', curgstartmonth?

Comment: @habibg updated explanation for your reference. Please note, in the above example I considered the year difference to be 1 and hence added 12 to calcEndMonth. If more than a year diff is possible then, you have to add 12*yearDiff and change the logic accordingly.